# Getting value of jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

html

```
<h1>HTML Slider Test</h1>
<div class="slider" data-max="100"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<input type="button" value="send" class="send">
<div class="slider" data-max="400"></div>
<p>Your slider has a value of <span class="slider-value"></span></p>
<input type="button" value="send" class="send">
```

jQuery

```
var a = 0;

$(".slider").each(function() {
    $(this).slider({
        value : 5,
        min   : 1,
        max   : $(this).data('max'),
        step  : 1,
        slide : function (event, ui) {
           a = ui.value;
           $(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
        }
    });
});

$(".send").click(function () {
    var c=$(".slider-value").text();
    alert(c);  
});
```

on clicking first button i want value of that alone..but i am getting the value of both sliders.
http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1906/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".slider-value")` is returning both fields. Use Refiners to get a specific one.

Example:

```
$(".slider-value").first()
$(".slider-value").last()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1909/

### Dynamic solution

Simply create the button and its click event on the fly (or attach to an inline button) when creating the slider.

```
var a = 0;
$(".slider").each(function() {
    var slider = this;
    $(slider).slider({
        value : 5,
        min   : 1,
        max   : $(this).data('max'),
        step  : 1,
        slide : function (event, ui) {
           a = ui.value;
           $(this).next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
        }
    });
    var button = $('<button>send</button>');
    $(button).click(function() {
       alert( $(slider).slider("option", "value"));
    });
    $(slider).next().find('span.slider-value').after($("<br />"), button);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jgod5e2p/)**

Comment: what happens when he adds a third one? Also: now both buttons alert both values.

Comment: @DoXicK noone said that the solution should be dynamic - I just pointed out the problem and provided a solution. 
But just for you I added a dynamic solution without the need to maintain a `data-slider` attribute per slider :)

Comment: didn't say it had to be dynamic, just said that your solution is unmaintainable in the long run. You don't have to post a solution just for me since i'm not the one needing it. I do however like the fact that you used the sliders' value instead of an intermediate value.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way of identifying the slider value you want to take, which currently wasn't possible without hardcoding it: `.prev().prev().find(...blabla)`, which is a bad way of doing it, since your structure might change.

I updated your jsfiddle to make it work and give an example of how to easily do this using a data attribute and an ID: http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1908/

You basicly give the button a selector of what element it is 'bound' to: `data-slider="#slider-value-2"`

You also give the slider value an id that matches that selector: `id="slider-value-2"`

Modify the onClick function:

```
var $this = $(this);
var c=$($this.attr('data-slider')).text();
```

Now you have a flexible way of retrieving values and binding elements to the buttons without being dependent on the dom. I suggest using the same technique for binding the value elements to the slider itself.

---

While i'm at it: cache the value of `$(this)`, it's faster and saves you a lot of scoping issues if you expand your code.

```
$(".slider").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.slider({
        value : 5,
        min   : 1,
        max   : $this.data('max'),
        step  : 1,
        slide : function (event, ui) {
           a = ui.value;
           $this.next().find('span.slider-value').html(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but the first slider value is not alerted

Comment: because i did not fix that one. i only fixed the second one.

Comment: i need both the values

Comment: then you should apply the stuff i posted here to the other elements. I suggest you bind it to the slider though and get the value of the jquery slider itself.